# Extracting XML data, modifying it and storing in excel file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I am new to asp.net. I have an xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<newsitem itemid="10000" id="root" date="1996-08-22" xml:lang="en">
  <title>CHINA: China says hopeful on global nuclear test ban.</title>
  <headline>China says hopeful on global nuclear test ban.</headline>
  <dateline>BEIJING 1996-08-22</dateline>
  <text>
    <p>China said on Thursday it was hopeful a global nuclear test ban treaty could be approved by the U.N. </p>
    <p>&quot;China hopes that the treaty could be open for signature by the end of the year and that there .</p>
    </text>
.....continue
```

The xml file is huge, I want that..i have to Process only terms in the ‹title› and ‹text› fields of each news item. Also, I have to count the frequency of those words.

I tried to extract the text from title and text field. I got data for title field but not getting for text field. Moreover, in the title field, I am not getting unique elements, the elements are getting repeated. Please help me.

The code I tried is :

```
 string filename = Server.MapPath("demo1.xml");
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(filename);
        XmlNodeType type;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            type = reader.NodeType;

            if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (reader.Name == "text")
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    TextBox1.Text = reader.Value;
                }

              if (reader.Name == "title")
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(reader.Value);

                }

            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
```

In the listbox, I am getting data but in text box i am not getting data. Moreover, i need to store huge xml data and count the the number of each words. for example china-2, says-1 and store it in excel. Would you tell me should i use string builder and if yes, how ?

Comment: Use `XDocument` and LINQ to XML for this.  It will make your life so much easier.

Comment: @Yuck I have no idea about LINQ,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
var xml = XElement.Load(new FileStream(@"C:\TEMP\TEST.xml", FileMode.Open));

var titleElement = xml.Elements("title").SingleOrDefault();
var title = titleElement != null ? titleElement.Value : String.Empty;
var textElement = xml.Elements("text").SingleOrDefault();
var text = textElement != null
               ? String.Join(String.Empty, textElement.Elements()
                                                      .Select(t => t.Value))
               : String.Empty;
```

I am using your above XML snippet as an example.  You'll want to adapt it to your final XML structure, but I think with the above pattern you should be able to make it suit your needs.

The variable `title` will be the text of the `<title>` element and the variable `text` will be the concatenated text of all elements found within the `<text>` element.  In this way you end up with `String` variables which you can perform standard text processing on to achieve your goal of getting word counts, etc.

Hope this helps!